# fo:for-each is not a valid child of fo:table-row

Tags: java, apache, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm using Apache FOP 2.1 for generating PDF documents inside a simple java application.

When it comes to generate a table with dynamic rows then it always ends in an error:
`(Position des Fehlers unbekannt)org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:for-each" is not a valid child of "fo:table-row"! (Keine Kontextinformationen verfügbar)`

My xml input looks like:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<invoicedata>
  <invoice>
    <positions>
      <position>
        <posOrder>1</posOrder>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
      </position>
      <position>
        <posOrder>2</posOrder>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
      </position>
    </positions>
  </invoice>
</invoicedata>
```

My xsl fo template looks like:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
  exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
  <xsl:template match="invoicedata">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm"
          margin-top="0.5cm" margin-bottom="0.5cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm">
          <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" margin-bottom="3.5cm" margin-top="5cm" />
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>

      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" font-size="10pt">
          <xsl:if test="invoice/positions">
            <fo:block>
              <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt"                >
                <fo:table-column column-width="7%" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" />
                <fo:table-column column-width="8%" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" />
                <fo:table-header background-color="gray">
                  <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" >
                      <fo:block text-align="center">Pos.</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" >
                      <fo:block text-align="center">Menge</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-body>
                  <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:for-each select="invoice/positions">
                    <fo:table-cell >
                      <fo:block text-align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="posOrder" />
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell >
                      <fo:block text-align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="quantity" />
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:for-each>
                  </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
              </fo:table>
            </fo:block>
          </xsl:if>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, atm I have no clue how to configure the for-each element to generate a table with dynamic rows.

Comment: I bet you meant `<xsl:for-each>`, not `<fo:for-each>`...

Comment: @potame: Thanks a lot - you saved my day! After hours of xml reading I didn't recognized the namespace problem... Now it works fine!

Comment: @potame, you should post as an answer and the OP can accept. It is much nicer on Stackoverflow to see closed issues than open to help folks learn and see the answered questions.

Comment: @KevinBrown well, I kind of don't agree with you. This question is only related to a typo (this happens to everyone) and won't help anyone solving a problem. Typically this question should be closed with the following reason: "*This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.*"

Comment: Agreed, I had not thought it was a typo.